# how to append/insert an item at the beginning of a series?

Tags: python, pandas

imaging i have a series looks like this:

```
Out[64]: 
2      0
3      1
80     1
83     1
84     2
85     2
```

how can i append an item at the very beginning of this series? the native pandas.Series.append function only appends at the end.

thanks a lot

Comment: to do that kind of breaks the intent of pandas.Series ... you will likely see that it takes much much longer to insert at the begining of a series than at the end.  are you sure that `Pandas.Series` is the right data structure for your problem?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Whay you say usually relates to python list, not to pandas.Series. Can you provide a benchmark how prepending a Series takes significantly longer than appending to it (that does not involve copying to python list and back)?

Answer (score 31):

There is a `pandas.concat` function...

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([2,3,4])
pd.concat([pd.Series([1]), a])
```

See the [Merge, Join, and Concatenate documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

Comment: this causes duplication of index

Comment: If the original index is not important, one could ``print(pd.concat([pd.Series([1]), a], ignore_index=True))``

Answer (score 15):

Using concat, or append, the resulting series will have duplicate indices:

for concat():

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([2,3,4])
pd.concat([pd.Series([1]), a])

Out[143]: 
0    1
0    2
1    3
2    4
```

and for append():

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([2,3,4])
a.append(pd.Series([1]))

Out[149]: 
0    2
1    3
2    4
0    1
```

This could be a problem in the future, since a[0] (if you assign the result to a) will return two values for either case.

My solutions are in this case:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([2,3,4])
b = [1]
b[1:] = a
pd.Series(b)

Out[199]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
```

or, by reindexing with concat():

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([2,3,4])
a.index = a.index + 1  
pd.concat([pd.Series([1]), a])

Out[208]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
```

Comment: "or, by reindexing with concat()"
This is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to prepend a single value from a different Series `b`, say its last value, this is what works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([2, 3, 4])
b = pd.Series([0, 1])
pd.concat([b[-1:], a])
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, you can use append with a list or tuple of series (so long as you're using pandas version .13 or greater)

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([2,3,4])
pd.Series.append((pd.Series([1]), a))
```