# Adding an item on top & bottom of series pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
0.0
3.0
7.0
11.0
15.0
18.0
```

I am trying to add 2 values (-1000 & 2000) on top and bottom of the column like this:

```
-1000
0.0
3.0
7.0
11.0
15.0
18.0
2000
```

I tried `df.insert(0, -1000)` but I get the following error:

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to append/insert an item at the beginning of a series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994543/how-to-append-insert-an-item-at-the-beginning-of-a-series)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try look at `append`

```
s=pd.Series([-1000]).append(s.append(pd.Series([2000]))).reset_index(drop=True)
```